# c# How to get Dataset contents in loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a Dataset **ds1** and I have selected a column in it from a table.

```
da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select column from table", con); // con is the connection string
da.Fill(ds1, "column");
```

Then I assigned the contents from first row to a string array **getitems[]** as follows:

```
getitems[0] = (ds1.Tables[0].Rows[0]["column"].ToString());
```

Every thing is working fine if I use it in this way but the data set contains 600 rows.I used the above statement in a loop but I am getting an error. Here is the code:

```
for(int i=0; i<=600; i++) {

getitems[i] = (ds1.Tables[i].Rows[i]["column"].ToString());
dt.Rows.Add(getitems[i]);
//dt is another data set and is putting the data on a data grid
}
```

I am get this exception on the line where I am assigning the contents to string array:

```
Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Cannot find table 1.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
for(int i=0; i<600; i++) {
    getitems[i] = Convert.ToString(ds1.Tables[0].Rows[i]["column"]);
    //Some logic
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your DataSet doesn't have 600 tables!

This isn't right - `Tables[i]`

Use the loop for just the rows and instead of using 600 use `Count` on the rows or use a foreach loop. Something like:

```
 var dt = ds1.Tables[0];
 foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) 
 {
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
```

Comment: +1, thats the correct answer, I didn't see that the OP is looping on tables.

Comment: My answer assumes there is one table - that might not be right. How many tables are you expecting?

Comment: the query in question should return a single table.